# Why is there a syntax error in my React component class?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class, refs

I have a syntax error in my code, and I'm not sure why. Does it have to do with the way I used refs?

```
export default class ToggleMenu extends React.Component {

  showRight: function() {
    this.refs.right.show();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.showRight}>Show Left Menu!</button>
      {/*  
        <Menu ref="right" alignment="right">
          <MenuItem hash="1">First</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem hash="2">Second</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem hash="3">Third</MenuItem>
        </Menu> 
      */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

> `./src/components/ToggleMenu/` `ToggleMenu.js` Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:14)
>
> ```
> showRight: function() {
>   this.refs.right.show();  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting object literals and classes mixed up. Your code is inside a class, not an object literal, so you must use method definition syntax like you did with `render`. Classes can only contain prototypal methods and a constructor (as of ECMAScript 2015):

```
showRight() {
  this.refs.right.show();
}
```

Or else it will be interpreted as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and a function declaration, but function declarations with the `function` keyword cannot be in class bodies thus the syntax error:

```
showRight: //label
function() { //function declaration, not valid in class body!
    ...
}
```

Also, make sure to `bind(this)` to your methods so that `this` refers to the component and not the global scope's `this` value:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.showRight = this.showRight.bind(this);
}
```

Read more about [class bodies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions) at MDN.

---

Regarding your use of `ref`s, you should use a callback instead of a plain string:

```
<Menu ref={right => this.right = right} alignment="right">
```

Then in your `showRight`:

```
this.right.hide();
```

Comment: ok that make sense thank u but at least why im geting the next error:                 uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: @Alex are you sure you're putting it in the constructor?

Comment: `export default class ToggleMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.showRight = this.showRight.bind(this);
}


  render() {


    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.showRight}>Show Left Menu!</button>

    {/* <Menu ref={right => this.right = right} alignment="right">
      <MenuItem hash="1">First</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="2">Second</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="3">Third</MenuItem>
      </Menu> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}`  yes im sure .. can u please tell me whats wrong

Comment: Well, there is no `showRight` function in your example.